# Bought a used surface book online, any security precautions to take?

Tags: hardware, account-security, ssd

I have purchased a used surface book from Ebay, unpackaged and ran the device.

The low price of the device lured me in despite my adverse attitude to used devices. Is there anything I need to perform apart from re-installing windows, perhaps a complete re-install rather than just a “clean” to ensure nothing is hiding there e.g a virus?

Comment: [Nuke it from orbit.](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1118/86741)