# What are the risks of buying used gadgets?

Tags: mobile

Thinking of buying a used iPhone and MacBook. Probably an iPhone 7/8/X and MBP 2015. As a security conscious (many would say overly paranoid) person I'm considering the risks. I'm quite sure I'm not someone specifically targeted by state-sponsored hackers or anything like that.

What security risks would I face and how do I mitigate them? Would a factory reset of an iPhone be sufficient to rid it of anything the previous owner might have had on the phone - malware perhaps? For the MBP I'm thinking just replacing the storage drive with a new one, but not sure about firmware level malware.

Comment: This is looking like a duplicate of: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180217/bought-a-used-surface-book-online-any-security-precautions-to-take

Comment: If your question is "how to reset Apple device firmware back to factory defaults and be sure about it" then that might be better asked on apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: "Nuke it from orbit" isn't really a helpful answer here though. Is that really the only answer?

Comment: He risks are that there is a lingering infection. The remedy is to reset to a known good factory default. That's a nuke from orbit.